# Combine multiple REST enpoints into one

Tags: rest, caching, spring-data, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm looking for design pattern/library to combine multiple different endpoint to be visible as one.

Let's say I have 3 endpoints, each of them returns the same type of objects, of course objects are different and have unique id. I want to create an endpoint which calls all of them, combine results, filter & sort & page, then return results.

There can be many objects, so it could be good to have caching, to call those three endpoints only when something has changed (let's say I somehow know if I need to refresh cache).

I imagine there's a library which can connect multiple endpoint into one, cache results and deliver filter & sort & page. Some sort of, let's say, Spring repository: however data are not read from database, but from cache, which gathers them from REST endpoints.

I was looking at Gateway design pattern like Spring Gateway or Zuul Proxy, but it seems to be only a wrapper, no possibility process data.

Of course I can do such things manually:

- create controller
- call three endpoints (if needed to refresh)
- fill cache
- read data from cache sort, filter, page, and return them

but if I need to do that multiple times, I'm looking for library to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the [GatewayFilterFactory](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/spring-cloud-gateway.html#_writing_custom_gatewayfilter_factories) with aggregation and caching in Spring Cloud Gateway.  But it looks like the creation of a controller.

Comment: I've ended up with custom library. Cache is in memory structure, filtering etc is done via String predicates. GatewayFilterFactory  seems promising but as I have working solution now, I will not invest time in checking it :)